# Multiple domain SSL / SNI with pkcs12 (.p12) and SSLContext?

Tags: java, scala, ssl, akka-http

How do I enable multiple domain ssl using SSLContext?  In this particular case, akka-http will be used.

For example, consider dozens of domains, each with their own key, cert, bundles like this:

```
a.com
private key
certificate
intermediate certs/bundle

b.com
... similar to above ...

etc.
```

Do I create a p12 (pkcs12) from all these files?  How?  Are all the private keys included?

Or do I create multiple p12 files and configure an SSLContext that references all of them?

Or do I create multiple SSLContexts' and reference all of them when initializing the akka-http server?

Thank you!